# have a url that accepts all characters

Tags: python, django

I want a url that accepts all characters,for example:

```
(r'^company/(?P<key>[a-zA-Z]+)/doclist/$','CompanyHub.views.docList')
```

for `key` parameter instead of just ascii alphabetic characters It accepts all characters include numbers,symbols like $,-,_,...,alphabet,unicode characters,...

how can I do this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```
(ur'^company/(?P<key>.*)/doclist/$','CompanyHub.views.docList')
```

We need the 'u' at the beginning to tell python that the string accepts unicode characters.

Answer (score 15):

RegEx would look like this:

```
(.*)
```

That should match all characters except new line characters.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said:

```
(.*)
```

...will match all characters, but it will also match an empty string (which might be bad if the regex is at the end of a URL). If you want to force that at least one character is required, then use this:

```
(.+)
```

Just to be clear, these work in the middle of URLs as well as at the end, so something like this works perfectly fine:

```
url(ur'^package\/(?P<pkgname>.+)\/(?P<pkgversion>.+)', ... )
```

(and as @tsikov says, use a preceding 'u' for unicode)